# Having some folder in svn(its adress) how to check out exact time it was modified last time?

Tags: linux, svn, file, directory

so we have a folder. it is under svn. we do not want to download all svn, ither that folder. We want to get the latest date of any of its contents (any file, any sub folder) last modification, and we want to get which file was modificated last. So example folder `http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension` . So how to do such thing?

BTW: can we get such info from svn server via browser?

Comment: try `svn log -v http://cloudobserver.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v0.4/Boost.Extension.Tutorial/libs/boost/extension/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've found a command reference, you should be able to just do:

```
svn info http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension
```

Which should output like:

```
Path: foo.c
Name: foo.c
URL: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/foo.c
Revision: 4417
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: sally
Last Changed Rev: 20
Last Changed Date: 2003-01-13 16:43:13 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)
Text Last Updated: 2003-01-16 21:18:16 -0600 (Thu, 16 Jan 2003)
Properties Last Updated: 2003-01-13 21:50:19 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)
Checksum: /3L38YwzhT93BWvgpdF6Zw==
```

This probably being the important line:

```
Last Changed Date: 2003-01-13 16:43:13 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)
```

For reference, since I can never find it... subversion helps available [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html)

Comment: The ["Nightly Build"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html) version of the book covers the most recent versions of svn.  Or there's always [the book's home page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 0):

svn info -v the path for the folder

and about to see the svn in the browser you need to install websvn http://www.websvn.info/

Comment: does not work for me at all, `rupert@linux:~> svn info -v http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension
Subcommand 'info' doesn't accept option '-v [--verbose]'
Type 'svn help info' for usage.` While `svn log` gives way 2 many info.

Comment: @Kabumbus: do you get enough info if you just do `svn info  http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost/extension`

Comment: the -v "revision no." you must follow the -v with revision no.

Answer (score 0):

I use svn log for most things:

```
svn log -l 1 url
```